# Авторизация через Яндекс при помощи Spring

Tags: java, spring, авторизация

Я делаю приложение на фреймворке Spring. Хочу сделать авторизацию через Яндекс. Своё приложение я уже зарегистрировал со следующими правами:
Права:

1.Доступ к логину, имени и фамилии, полу

2.Доступ к адресу электронной почты

3.Доступ к портрету пользователя

Но как сделать авторизация через API  Яндекса, я не представляю.
Помогите пожалуйста с решением этой проблемы(если можно подскажите с самим алгоритмом, или укажите ссылку с примером, пожалуйста).

Comment: [Янедкс oAuth](https://tech.yandex.com/oauth/) и [Яндекс App Authorization](https://tech.yandex.com/money/doc/dg/concepts/money-oauth-intro-docpage/)

Comment: [документация на русском языке](https://yandex.ru/dev/oauth/doc/dg/reference/web-client-docpage/)